# How do I create an option to convert mouse left/right handed in Windows with JS?

Tags: javascript, windows, shell, cmd

Hope you are having a good day. I´m trying to implement an option for lefty/righty handed mouse users in context menu for Windows with JavaScript without jQuery.

Is for a desktop Vue app, but cannot find a way to implement it.

I implemented this option in Linux OS and I´m trying to replicate it in Win OS, but cannot find a good way for it.

I tried with shell/cmd commands like `RUNDLL32.EXE USER32.DLL,SwapMouseButton` but only runs in one way, I cannot revrse it.

Also tried triggering mouse click buttons, but also failed in that one too.

If someone knows an option, let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The question is unclear.  Is this for a native Windows app, Node.js, a web page?

Comment: @Yogi true, I will edit now the question, but it´s a Vue desktop app.

Comment: SwapMouseButton accepts a Boolean value to enable/disable button swap. However, this will not work with RUNDLL32 because it automatically sets the first method parameter to the window handle.  So passing true/false or 1/0 has no effect as you noted in question. The workaround is probably using [Vue Desktop PInvoke](https://www.vuedesktop.com/native-win32-interop) which can call USER32.  Looking at the Vue examples, it seems you could then pass the Boolean to enable/disable button swap.